# RecyclerView - findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() returns null for invisible items

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update all views on `RecyclerView` item click. I tried `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()` to get the `ViewHolder` but it returns `null` for invisible items. I understand that the method can return `null` if view is not yet prepared and it won't be a wise idea to update other invisible lists if the list is huge. However, my list is very small (always less than 10) and I want to get access to views/viewholders upon an item click.

I am using the following code to update the ViewHolders

```
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
            if (i != getAdapterPosition()) {

                MyViewHolder temp = (MyViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);

                if (temp != null) {
                    //update elements
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "temp is null");
                }


            }
        }
```

Any help or leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess there is no workaround because it´s unsafe to use this method. It´s not guaranteed that the views are ready at this time you call the method. You should implement item click inside your adapter, not in the activity.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, yes I am using click listener in Adapter. The problem is, I am not getting access to ViewHolders of invisible list items.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get access to views/viewholders upon an item click.

You can simply achieve this functionality by setting onClickListener on any view, inside the onBindViewHolder() method of your adapter.

For dispatching the click event on an item to an activity or fragment for handling :

1- In your adapter class, define an interface called OnItemClickListener :

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
     void onItemClicked(int position, AnyOtherDataYouWant data)
}
```

2- Make your activity or fragment implement this interface

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener
```

3- Pass a reference of type `OnItemClickListener` interface to the `constructor of your adapter` and save it in an field, called `listListener` .

4- In the `onBindViewHolder` of your adapter, on the view you want like a button or a textview :

```
holder.myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view)
    {
         listListener.onItemClicked(position, AnyDataYouWant data) ;
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not exactly I need. What I need is to update all list items upon an item click. For example, you have a list and you need to show a check image upon an item click. However, you need to uncheck other lists so that only one item check will be shown.

Comment: Even easier. you should keep track of the position of the checked item in your adapter, and when an item is cliked call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(). @AjmalSalim

Comment: Also, in your onBindViewHolder, check if the current position is equal to the saved checked position and call setChecked(true) for example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've managed to solve it by saving the ViewHolders to an array and later updating that array. :)

Comment: That's actually wrong because you force all of them to be alive in the memory and this is against the whole idea behind viewholder pattern.

Comment: I have tried adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(), but it does not work as expected. All I need is to update the whole list when on item click. As I mentioned, the list will be always less than 10.

Comment: There is something wrong with how you are managing the checked item state. you can edit your question while providing more code so that we can see what the real issue is.